# Limiting requests by client with asynchronous JavaScript to the server for data

Tags: javascript, security, asynchronous, authorization, ddos

I have an asynchronous JavaScript function which fetches data from the server. However, I've noticed that if a user goes into their console in the browser, they can repeatedly call this function from the console and make endless requests to the server to fetch data.

This question is about website security and request authorizations. I want to limit the client to making one request to the server for data per page visit so that the data fetching resources on the back end can't be DDOS'd.

Do I need to build a system on the backend to make it so that only one request to the server to fetch data per page visit is allowed, and the user can't spam this function on the client side? Or can the number of requests being made to the server be limited to one on the client side using JS?

Here is my JS code as an example

```
var numberOfRequests = 0;

async function getResults() {
    if(numberOfRequests !== 0){
        return;
    }
    
    numberOfRequests = numberOfRequests + 1;
    console.log("Fetching data");

  var postData = {
    test: "test"
  };

  const response = await fetch("https://example.com/test.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'
    },
    //make sure to serialize your JSON body
    body: JSON.stringify({
      postData
    })
  });

  const data = await response.text();

  if(data){
    console.log(data)
  }
}

getResults();
```

Comment: As you noticed, a user can copy and paste javascript into the console.  So if you want to implement some kind of effective rate limiter, it will need to be on the server.

Comment: You can try promise-ratelimit as mentioned below
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70703454/14115212

Comment: there is no good solution on client side, at best you will prevent yourself to ddos your server. If someone really wants to perform a DDOS attack, he will not even bother finding a potential global method that uses `fetch`, he will just have a look at this network, copy a request as curl/node.js and send you requests from a script. The only protection you can have is on server side.