# How to limit the download speed while using node-fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have the following logic (example is very simplified):

```js
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const filePath = "C:\\Downloads\\";

const fileName = path.basename(url);
const fullFilePath = path.join(filePath, fileName);

const response = await fetch(url, options);

const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(fullFilePath);
response.body.pipe(fileStream);

response.body.on("data", (chunk: Buffer) => {
// ... track progress
});


response.body.on("end", () => {
  fileStream.end();
  fileStream.close();
  // ... report complete event
});
```

My question is: How can I limit the download speed.
Because this will be used in the context of ElectronJS application, I want to allow the user to set the maximum allowed download speed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to throttle my JS API fetch requests, using the rate-limit supplied by the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595420/how-to-throttle-my-js-api-fetch-requests-using-the-rate-limit-supplied-by-the-h)

Comment: Short answer: no. Neither the Fetch API nor Electron offer any sort of bandwidth controls.

Comment: You can't control download speed when using `response.body.on("data", ...)` or `response.body.pipe(fileStream);` because that will just generate events as fast as the data arrives.  You could NOT use event driven logic on the stream and just do reads on the stream directly and if you slow down the pace at which you do your reads, then eventually, the stream will cause backpressure and tell the host to pause sending.  It's not a very direct control, but it could slow things down.  Mostly, you really want this to be controlled by the sender.

Comment: @jfriend00 so what you are suggesting is, if I want to implement a download limit I should handle it on the server side ? Basically passing it as argument to the request ? That of course implies that the file that I want to download should be served via API endpoint that I can control, which technically is possible. I just somehow thought that the download speed is and can be controlled by the client.

Comment: The server will send a response as fast as it can - that is its job unless it explicitly implements a feature to slow down its sending of the response.  The only way the client can slow things down from its end of things is to not read the data that is waiting and that will eventually cause the TCP stack to go into flow-control to tell the server to stop sending new data (allowing for various buffers in both client and server).

Comment: So, if you control the server endpoint code, then it would be best to implement a sending rate there on the server and if the client can send the desired rate as part of the request,, then that would work.

Comment: @jfriend00 I disagree with handling this on the server side. TCP flow control is the perfect tool for this - and it's already implemented and active anyway. Slow reading is the way to go.

Comment: May have to be aware of server-side timeouts if the client slows things way down.